# Javascript download image one time set src of two image tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do some performance improvement on a web page that I'm building, and one of the things that I'm doing is, using javascript, downloading an image by creating an `Image()` object, and settings its `src` attribute to a given URL.

I'm then handling the `onload` event of that object, and in the handler, I'm using the objects `src` attribute to set the `src` attribute of two `<img>` elements on the page. What I was *hoping* that would do was only download the image one time, and then use that downloaded image as the `src` of the two image elements on the page, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening.

From what I can tell by viewing Network information using Firebug and Google Chrome dev tools, setting the `src` attribute of the two image elements on the page appears to result in actually downloading the image twice, once for each set.

Its the same image, and its rather large...so the download is time-consuming. Is there a way that I can force the image to only be downloaded once? Here's my code:

```
var image = new Image()

image.onload = function () {
    $('#img1').attr('src', image.src);
    $('#img2').attr('src', image.src);
    image = null;
}

image.src = 'my/image/url';
```

**UPDATE**: This is what is causing me to believe that the image is being downloaded twice. Again...I could be wrong, maybe this is misleading, but if Chrome dev tools is reporting two different "resources" on the Network tab, each with the same path, the same file size, but different timings, wouldn't that indicate that its actually being downloaded twice? Maybe my problem is with the dev tools I'm using, I dunno...

[image]

Comment: Just curious, from your code it doesn't look like the image changes. Have you considered doing this not with jQuery but with some CSS manipulation?

Comment: What makes you think that the image will be downloaded more than once? The browsers will download the image and place it in the cache. If the same image appears again on the web-page, it will be loaded from cache.

Comment: @skyburner: I'd not considered that, but this is only a small subset of my code. Each of these images actually does get manipulated, and each by other jQuery plugins on the page, so I don't think that would be an option for this situation. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I certainly could be wrong about that, but as I mentioned, the Network viewer in both Firebug and Google Chrome dev tools seemed to indicate to me that the image was being downloaded twice, though maybe that's just because I don't understand how those tools work. Maybe they are misleading?

Comment: @BobYexley Could you post a screenshot of your network viewer where it shows that the image is downloaded twice?

Answer (score 3):

`src` is nothing but the `url` pointing to the image on the server. If you set the src of the image it will refresh the image.

Browsers do cache images if the url do not change. Even if you see a image request in the console but it is still coming from the cache unless you have disabled caching.

Modern browsers support Local storage where you can cache any static resource you want. Take a look at this jQuery Image Cache plugin it might be helpful to you.

http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-image-cache-plugin-cache-images-in-browsers-local-storage/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the background image to a class and add that class to elements you need.

When you are assigning the second src, the browser will check the server if the image is changed (might be using some file hash mechanism), if both the images in the server and in the cache is same, browser will load the image from the cache, still you will see a request to servers in Firebug console.